# Is there a form of lazy evaluation where a function (like mean) returns an approximate value when operating on arrays

Tags: python, machine-learning, lazy-evaluation

For example we want to calculate mean of a list of numbers where the list is so long. and that numbers when sorted are nearly linear (or we can find a linear Regression Model for data). Mathematically we can aggregate mean by

```
((arr[0] + arr[length(arr)]) / 2 )   + intercept
```

Or in the case, linear model is nearly constant (slope coefficient is nearly 1). we can calculate approximately:

```
mean(arr[n/const]) = mean(arr)
```

The same concept is applied for the two cases. and is so basic. 
Is there a way: pattern, function (hopefully in python), or any studies to suggest and that can help will be gratefully welcome; of course such a pattern if exists should be general and not only for the mean case (probably any function 
 or at least aggregate functions like: sum, mean ...). (as I don't have a strong mathematical background, and I'm new to machine learning, please tolerate my ignorance).
Please let me know if anything is not clear.

Comment: What does this have to do with machine learning?

Comment: I thought my simple solution: getting a linear model from a portion of data in order to have a future view of the rest is a way of prediction ? but that is what I thought of as a solution, and I'm not limited to

Comment: if a linear model is nearly constant, the slope would be nearly **0**

Comment: I don't get it.  Your array is too big to perform an aggregate function over, but somehow you know it is sorted?  Is this just a hypothetical question, or is this an actual problem that you can provide some more detail?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Law of Large Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers) states that as sample size increases, an average of a sample of observations converges to the true population average with probability 1.

Therefore, if your hypothetical array is too big to average, you could at the very least take average of a large sample and know that you are close to the true population mean.

You can sample from a `numpy` array using [`numpy.random.choice(arr,n)`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) where `arr` is your array and `n` is as many elements as you wish (or are able) to sample.

Comment: I think I will stick with that, I think sampling is the only solution, I've been turning and turning for no reason :o

Comment: @Curcuma_ If you array fits in memory (required for sampling like this) then surely it's not too large to calculate the mean of?

Answer (score 2):

There are more general solutions to such jobs like Dask package, for example: http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/
It can optimize calculation graphs, parallelize calculation and many more.

Comment: Dask seems to be my savor,  I never heard of!